# Recommendation laptop for productivity and some gaming?

Tags: laptop

I'm planning on buying a new `laptop` for some productivity and maybe a bit of gaming too.

These are the main specs/price I want to get:

- **Processor**: `Intel i7`
- **Disk**: `256GB SSD + 1TB HDD` or `512GB SSD`
- **Ram**: `16GB`
- **Graphic Card**: something similar to the `nVidia GeForce GTX1050 4Gb`
- **Screen**: could be `14 inches` or `15 inches`
- **Price**: maximum `1500 EUR`

The only option I could found was the model:

```
ASUS Vivobook Pro 15 N580
```

Is there any similar options, even for other brands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [MSI GX63VR €1.375,99 + €23,62 International Shipping (MSRP: €1.460,99)](https://www.newegg.com/global/pt/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834154732&ignorebbr=1)

[image: MSI GX63]

This is a VR capable laptop that can ship to Lisbon, Portugal in under 5 business days (I took the liberty of checking the location on your stack-exchange profile). I decided to recommend you a laptop equipped with a GTX 1070 as [benchmarks suggest this laptop will outperform the ASUS Vivobook Pro 15 N580's GTX 1050 by 186%](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-1050-Mobile-vs-Nvidia-GTX-1070-Mobile/m211022vsm164129). 1080 setups, unfortunately were over budget [despite outperforming 1070 setups by 22%](http://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-1070-Mobile-vs-Nvidia-GTX-1080-Mobile/m164129vsm165564). In addition, this laptop comes equipped with an PCI-e M.2 SATA SSD.

- Nvidia GTX 1070 8 GB
- i7-7700 HQ
- 16 GB Memory
- 256 GB M.2 SATA SSD
- 1 TB HDD
- 15.6" 1080p

If you don't like buying laptops internationally, [here are some local stores in Lisbon that carry MSI laptops](https://es.msi.com/service/wheretobuy/#41,3,Lisbon). You seem to know what you're doing, so I don't think that you would have any trouble finding a couple MSI laptops to add to your options.

Answer (score 1):

[Dell G3579 $1350 + free shipping (1162.18 euro)](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA8X58582570)

[image]

- 8th Generation Intel Core i7-8750H Processor (6-Core, 9MB Cache, up
  to 3.9GHz w/Turbo Boost)
- 16GB 2666MHz DDR4 up to 32GB
- 256 GB (SSD) Boot + 1 TB 5400 RPM SATA HDD Storage , No ODD
- 15.6-inch FHD (1920 x 1080) IPS Anti-Glare, LED-Backlit Display
- Screen Size 15.6 inches
- Max Screen Resolution 1920 x 1080
- Processor 3.9 GHz Intel Core i7
- RAM 16 GB DDR4
- Hard Drive 1000 GB Mechanical Hard Drive
- Graphics Coprocessor NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

Note: Google search using "gaming laptop 500gb ssd 1tb hdd gtx 1050 16gb ram" gives a handful of options that fit your needs.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that your option doesn't ship to Portugal as you cannot enter a Portuguese zip code on the US Version of the site, and the item does not exist when the Newegg region is set to Portugal. Newegg's standard free shipping only applies to the US and sometimes Canada.